# AS3 is calling an xml node in a string a variable, what's going on here?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, nodes

I am working on a project that calls and searches an XML sheet that looks like this:

```
    <Searchtext Wordlookup="john smith">
        <location>$1</location>
        <Name>john smith</Name>
    </Searchtext>
```

and it continues like this for about 100+ people.

Now, my flash takes this data and allows the user to either click on a textbox (whose e.target.data.text is matched up to the xml using @Wordlookup) or type in the name of the person (again matching the textbox's content to @Wordlookup) which results in the location of that person lighting up (MC's are named the same as the location node for each). This end works perfectly fine using this code:

```
    var result:String = xmldata.Searchtext.(@Wordlookup == inputTxt.text.toLowerCase()).location.toString();
```

Now I want to do the opposite; click on a location, and the code will match up that movieclip's name to a location in my xml, and light up that location, and output the person's name in the textbox. Only problem in that Flash apparently thinks a node in my xml is now a variable that is undefined. I have looked high and low for a solution, but I just can't seem to solve it (it is probably simple, and I'll facepalm myself)
The error inducing code is this:

```
    var resultz:String = xmldata.Searchtext.(location.text() == inputTxt2.text()).Name.toString();
```

And the error produced is this:
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable location is not defined.

EDIT: I originally had inputTxt2.text as e.target.name, but I'm throwing it in a textbox for now just so I can see it's outputting something that will match my location nodes.

Not sure exactly why this is happening, thank you in advance for any help!

ANOTHER EDIT: 
So adding .*. :

```
 var resultz:String = xmldata.*.Searchtext.(location.text() == inputTxt2.text()).Name.toString();
```

stopped it from creating th node as a variable, but it still returns null. Is there a better way to return the name from the matching location? It seems like it just isn't recognizing that the MC's name matches nodes in the XML....

Answer (score 0):

```
    var xmldata:XML = new XML(
                <root>
                    <Searchtext Wordlookup="john smith">
                        <location>$1</location>
                        <Name>john smith</Name>
                    </Searchtext>
                </root>
            )

    var result1:String = xmldata.Searchtext.(@Wordlookup == "john smith").location.toString();
    trace(result1) // traces $1

    var result2:String = xmldata.Searchtext.(location == "$1").Name.toString()
    trace(result2) // traces john smith
```

Comment: This would work, but I don't want to have to write out code for each of the 100+ people. I'm trying to have it so it reads the output (in this case inputTxt2's data) and matches it up to what is in the xml. Thanks though!

Comment: then replace "$1" with inputTxt2.text and leave off the () since text is a property and not a method.

Comment: I have done that as well, and I still unfortunately get the error. Thats kind of why I'm soo curious, it seems it should work, but just doesn't.

Comment: do not do "xmldata.Searchtext.(location.text() == inputTxt2.text()).Name.toString()" instead do "xmldata.Searchtext.(location == inputTxt2.text).Name.toString()"

Comment: yeah, I did that as well. Still same error. I am curious if there is something I am doing that would cause this error as far as maybe having it as a string, but I cant think of another way.